# How can I corral a method which may contain it's own async calls without having write access to the file?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I have a set of files, module1.js, module2.js, module3.js, and each of these contains a return object which has property-methods that will be executed. The objects are inspected to determine the property names dynamically, and I can `.toString()` the methods.

The inner methods will almost certainly contain async calls, like this:

```
function doSomething(vars){
  var that = this,
      red = 'blue',
      up = 'down',
      one = 2;

   makeAsync(that,red,up,one,function(err,res){
      return makeDeep(res);
   }
}
```

How can I marshall these methods from a calling parent method to eventually return the value without actively having writeable access to the files module1.js, module2.js and module3.js. Assume those are cast in stone, and can never be edited. Anything else that's reasonable is fair game. Just please don't say "well, rewrite doSomething to pass in a CB and let the `makeDeep` be wrapped in the CB". Note that I'm calling this module from my own code, and note that `makeAsync` is whatever asynchronous methods the module-author wants to call.

---

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** I am the one writing `makeDeep` and I am the one including the module so I can do whatever you want in either of those two places, and `makeDeep` is injected into the module dynamically (I'm doing a mixin pattern) so if your solution relies on modifying `makeDeep` to work or something in the "parent" calling method, that is 100% reasonable and I'm all about that.

If this is the case, there's no "need" to have the `return` keyword before `makeDeep` but bonus points if the syntax does use those words (that heavily indicates to a developer that that's a code exit point, yes?)

---

Assume that module1.js looks like:

```
module.exports = function() {
    this.doSomething11 = function doSomething(vars){
      var that = this,
          red = 'blue',
          up = 'down',
          one = 2;

       makeAsync(that,red,up,one,function(err,res){
          return makeDeep(res);
       }
    }
}
```

module2.js

```
module.exports = function() {
    this.doSomething21 = function doSomething(vars){
      var that = this,
          red = 'blue',
          up = 'down',
          one = 2;

       makeAsync(that,red,up,one,function(err,res){
          return makeDeep(res);
       }
    };

    this.doSomething22 = function doSomething(vars){
      var that = this,
          red = 'blue',
          up = 'down',
          one = 2;

       makeAsync(that,red,up,one,function(err,res){
          return makeDeep(res);
       }
    };
}
```

module3.js

```
module.exports = function() {
    this.doSomething31 = function doSomething(vars){
      var that = this,
          red = 'blue',
          up = 'down',
          one = 2;

       makeAsync(that,red,up,one,function(err,res){
          return makeDeep(res);
       }
    };

    this.doSomething32 = function doSomething(vars){
      var that = this,
          red = 'blue',
          up = 'down',
          one = 2;

       makeAsync(that,red,up,one,function(err,res){
          return makeDeep(res);
       }
    };

    this.doSomething33 = function doSomething(vars){
      var that = this,
          red = 'blue',
          up = 'down',
          one = 2;

       makeAsync(that,red,up,one,function(err,res){
          return makeDeep(res);
       }
    }
}
```

Yes, the examples are contrived, because I'm more focused on concept than I am on actual specifics. They could be triply nested callbacks, or could use some sort of internal callbacks. Mostly I just want to know if there's a way to make this happen.

If not, how can I make it work for the users if I provide them a specific library and have them return into the library?

My goal is to end up replicating something similar to the ASP.NET style ActionResult, and I'm open to the idea of using Q, fibers or promises, but I'm missing something around the invocation to get it back when an async callback is used.

Comment: the more important question is what are you trying to do? and that `return makeDeep()` makes no sense.

Comment: how does the "return makeDeep()" 'make no sense'? I'm writing a framework for nodejs that does a more MVC pattern and less "straight through" and I want to step away from the Connect/Express style of app-writing. I understand _why_ those work, I just don't personally like that. So I'm looking at the .NET MVC framework as inspiration, and they process everything but the actual controller method, so I need the controller method to return control to the framework. Which means treat the controller method like it's a synchronous method. How does that help you now?

Comment: since it's async, the value isn't actually returned, so there's no point in `return fn()`. just `fn()` suffices.

Comment: and i don't know what all that mumbo jumbo means. it's best to give an example of an API.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I don't know that it actually causes a negative principle in the app because nothing has happened there. But I want to return data back to the calling method, so something should "return".

Comment: but it returns to the anonymous function, not the top level calling method

Comment: define: `give an example of an API`. I did. Would you like to see the entire un-refined mess of a codebase to waddle through, or would you rather have the above requirements and present an example that does what's intended without worrying about my sad example of current-code? (I would say I'm 40% of the way to an alpha-demonstration project). Also note that the current codebase would give you an unclear example because I'm circumventing what the above asks, and doing something entirely different. So you would be skewed in the wrong direction needlessly.

Comment: `returns to the anonymous function, not the top level calling method` is an excellent point, and specifically the one that I'm trying to figure out how to address. Besides, for the purposes of what I want, that is a syntactic sugar and not necessary. But yes, you're correct.

Comment: I expect at the end of the day I'm going to be advised to do something with Fibers in the `makeDeep` and the parent-coordinator. Which is fine. I would just like to see some sort of example that can coordinate them together, I suppose.

Comment: see i don't know what you're trying to do. I see 3 files that with the same pattern repeated over and over. each method does not use its arguments. `makeDeep` and `makeAsync` are not defined anywhere. I'm assuming what you really want is to create multiple versions of a function, each with different default values. i'm not sure because i need to see how you're using these functions, not how they are defined.

Comment: because it doesn't matter how it's being used internally, I just need to capture some information from them as they're being used. I've actually only written _one_ controller method as that's all I need to work right now. All it does is encapsulate it's variable values in a json object and spit it back out. Are you at all familiar with .NET MVC? `makeDeep` is basically going to be an `ActionResult`. `makeAsync` is just some async call, I don't care what the async call is. It just does something async. Ostensibly it's a DB call.

Comment: nope, not familiar. that's why i don't understand what you're trying to do. i feel like you're working too hard for a simple problem, but i think that's just because i don't know what you're trying to do.

Comment: In trying to think of a handful of ways to succintly describe what I wanted, it dawned on me what I needed was a way to handle a formalized callback, and process it when it needed to be processed. Which is exactly the sort of thing an EventEmitter does. So basically I need a listener on an event handler to do what I need. I'll need a little bit to write up something on this, but you have prompted me to figure out what I could not, that I was omitting IoC and SoC in my design. Success!

Comment: If you can figure out how to magically turn all this into an answer "aren't you using an EE? Can't you just have the `makeDeep` emit on your parent process emitter and respond to it there?" for IoC and SoC concerns, then I'll gladly give you the 400 rep bountyu.

Comment: using an EE is a much better approach as its more node.js-like. trying to bring a different mindset to node.js will just make things more complicated for you. unfortunately, i still don't know what you're doing so i can't help you yet. but having an epiphany is a good sign!

Comment: okay two things i need clarification on: how are `.doSomethingXX` being called? and are the variables `red`, `up`, `one` derived from `vars`? those are very crucial to the problem, as in its current form i don't know why you've done anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll have a go at your problem which only requires the required module to call `return that.makeDeep()` instead of just `return makeDeep()`. I know you did not want to change the called code, but hey, you can always use [burrito](https://github.com/substack/node-burrito) and change those lines dynamically (no write access needed).

**calling code**

```
var Controller = require('./module1');
assert(typeof Controller == 'function');

httpServer.on('request', function(req, res) {
    // I assume this is something you would do
    var vars = processReqParameters(req);
    var action = vars.action;
    var controller = new Controller();

    if(typeof controller[action] === 'function') {
        // now I assume that makeDeep will at one point
        // call res.end();
        var makeDeep = createMakeDeep(req, res, vars) // or other parameters

        // this is how we inject makeDeep in the controller
        var controllerInstance = Object.create(controller, {makeDeep: makeDeep});
        return controllerInstance[action](vars);
    }
    else {
        res.writeHead(404, 'Controller Not Found');
        res.end('Too bad\n');
    }
})
```

**called code**

```
module.exports = function() {
    this.myAction = function(vars)  {
        var that = this,
            red = 'blue',
            up = 'down',
            one = 2;

        makeAsync(that, red, up, one, function(err, res) {
            return that.makeDeep(res);
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: You are almost identical in the above to my implementation, however I'm trying to return the value into the thread right after your line `return controllerInstance[action](vars)` such as `var result =  controllerInstance[action](vars);` However, this is almost identical to what I'm doing. (there's a lot more logic happening here, fwiw) So how do we capture "result"? What you've done here (in my testing) doesn't actually yield a value for result on account of the function "ending" before the closure executes.

Comment: And how would I shove that into this and catch it in the makeDeep callback? And is there anyway to do it without the "makeDeep" being attached to "that"? See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14777916/how-can-i-corral-a-method-which-may-contain-its-own-async-calls-without-having/14809160#comment20729964_14777916

Comment: I'm seriously considering just making it an EventEmitter emit on account of I want it to call back into the parental controlling process. That way I can abstract the control of the process. Otherwise I've just got a waterfall and can't exactly jump back into the controlling process, so I lose a few things. I kind of like the idea of having it be handled by emitters anyways.

Comment: go for it. EventEmitters are the node way. fibers, not so much.

Comment: That's what I'm thinking too!